.cache directory in snakemake causes the error: Disk quota exceeded
Running a snakemake pipeline, I got the following error:
OSError: [Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded: '~/.cache/snakemake/snakemake/source-cache/runtime-cache/tmpgjt6rxfc/file/crex/proj'

When looking into the runtime-cache directory, I see hundreds of directories with names starting with tmp*.
My question is that what are these directories?
Can I just delete them?
Is there an automatic way of cleaning them in the snakemake workflow?

Without getting into details, of which I'm only vaguely familiar with, the .snakemake directory is used by snakemake to store containers/environments, communicate about job status when deploying on a cluster, to cache information about jobs (external jobids, code hashes, etc), and to record the snakemake output in logs.
If a workflow is running, do not modify it otherwise processes will crash and become inconsistent.  You may delete it if you are ok with:

Having to rebuild any containers or conda environments
Lose information on code changes that may require reruns
Lose information on if an output may be incomplete
Have a longer startup time on the next run

Note that the logs are always stored in the directory you run snakemake from, but the containers and caches are stored in the workdir, if set.  If you have a quota on your home directory, consider moving your outputs (and therefore most of the .snakemake directory) to scratch or somewhere with a larger quota.  Of course, if you just ran out of disk space entirely, you can safely clean this directory once execution completes normally.
